# Still life generator in conway game of life

Tags: matlab, math, conways-game-of-life

I was thinking about [still life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life_(cellular_automaton)) generator (it doesn't need to be strict). The code should be as simple as possible. I came up with this idea: Firstly I generate random matrix and then iterate though every element and check this two rules:
1. Live cell must have either 2 or 3 live neighbors.
2. Dead cell can have any number of live neighbors except 3.
If cell doesn't satisfy this rules, I toggle it (if it was dead, I make it alive etc.) untill it meets those rules. Unfortunately if I change one cell another needs to be fixed and it takes forever to stabilize.

I know you could just make X iterations of game of life untill it is sort of stabilize but there will be some oscilators that you need to handle and detect.

The question is:
**How I can search for still life easier? Can you share some code/ideas how you do it?**

Here is the code in matlab that I created according to my idea. The code is not working properly, especially the part where I'm trying to toggle the cell that meets the rules

```
% live cell must have either 2 or 3 live neighbors.
% dead cell can have any number of live neighbors except 3.

DIM = 20;
M = randi(2, DIM+1) - 1;
%zeros the bounds
M(1,:) = 0;
M(DIM,:) = 0;
M(:,1) = 0;
M(:,DIM) = 0;

    for x = 2:length(M)
        for y = 2:length(M)
            %M = double((M & neighbours == 2) | neighbours == 3);
            neighbours = conv2(M, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1], 'same'); % returns numbers of neighbours
            if neighbours(x,y) == 1 || neighbours(x,y) == 0
                M(x,y) = 0;
            end
            if M(x, y) == 1 && (neighbours(x,y) > 3) || M(x, y) == 0 && neighbours(x,y) == 3 % still life
                if M(x,y)
                    todel = neighbours(x, y)-3;
                else
                    todel = 1;
                end

                while todel
                    a = randi(3, 1) - 2; % randomly choose cell to toggle
                    b = randi(3, 1) - 2;
                    if (a || b)
                        M(x+a, y+b) = ~M(x+a, y+b); % toggle cell
                        sprintf('(%d, %d);;(%d, %d)',x, y, x+a, y+b)
                        neighbours = conv2(M, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1], 'same'); % returns numbers of neighbours
                        if ((M(x, y) == 1 && (neighbours(x,y) == 2 || neighbours(x,y) == 3)) ||  (M(x, y) == 0 && neighbours(x,y) ~= 3)) % still life
                            todel = todel-1;
                        end
                    end
                end
            end 

            M(1,:) = 0;
            M(DIM,:) = 0;
            M(:,1) = 0;
            M(:,DIM) = 0;
        end
    end
%end

imshow(M, 'InitialMagnification', 1000);
drawnow;
```

Comment: You seem to have two questions, and neither is clear. Just how do you define a "still life"? Do you mean a situation where the pattern oscillates between a finite number of states? Your second implied question comes from "The code is not working properly." If you want help with that you should see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RoryDaulton [Still life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life_(cellular_automaton)) . This is a life that doesn't change, even after inifitie number of interations. The "second question" as you wrote is not a question. I'm not trying to convince anyone to fix my code. I'm just givin a snippet that is a but wrong bit maybe it helps to understand my question. The quesiotn is **bold** so you can clearly see it.

Comment: @RoryDaulton OP wants to generate a [semi] random pattern that has characteristic of a still life

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I know the standard definition of "still life" and I have written multiple Game of Life simulations of my own, though not in Matlab. I asked about *your* definition of "still life" since your statements "it doesn't need to be strict" and "sort of stabilize but there will be some oscilators that you need to handle and detect" were not clear.

Comment: @RoryDaulton definition of still life is in the question "1. Live cell must have either 2 or 3 live neighbors. 2. Dead cell can have any number of live neighbors except 3". but generation of such a pattern seems that is not a trivial task

Comment: @RoryDaulton I mean that you can make X iterations of random pattern, stop and then delete all oscilators. Yeah it is a bit bad idea

Comment: @rahnema1 I based on [this](http://radicaleye.com/lifepage/stilledit.html) and found this [source](http://radicaleye.com/lifepage/StillLife.java) but there are no comments and it's quite hard to get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an NxN board, and set to random pixels. Then score the board with +1 for each pixel that changes. Then make a random mutation, if score goes up, reject it, if score goes down, accept. Realistically you'll probably have to use simulated annealing.

http://www.malcolmmclean.site11.com/www/SimulatedAnnealing/SimulatedAnnealing.html

or there are other search stratagems.
Eventually you should get a change == 0. The snag I can see is that this might be the trivial "dead" life.